# VB Script on windows Error: Object Required

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run this vbscript (.vbs) code on my local machine and server using command line.
It works correctly on my local machine but not on server.
I am getting Object Required Error:

```
Option Explicit

Private objFSO, objShell 
Private strHome, strHomeFolder, strUser, objNetUser
Private objConnection, objCommand, objRecordSet
Call Main

Sub Main()

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") ' open connection to access and manipulate DB
    objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"  'provider name OLE DB provider in ADSI
    If Err.Number<>0 Then
    WScript.Echo FormatDateTime(Now()) & " - Error : " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    Exit Sub
    End If
....
```

- Error: Object Required

Comment: Can you present the smallest possible amount of code that still raises the error?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and run it. Then tell us what line the error is being reported for.